# Copy whole folder tree with subfolders and files into a new destination

Tags: batch-file

I am using Windows 7 x64 and I want to copy some files and folders. How can I position myself into the folder I want to copy and move everything in it into a new destination?

I've tried some solutions from stack  but non of them worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+copy+folder+and+subfolders

Edit:

I tried this code

```
for /d /r "c:\" %%i in (*) do if exist "d:\newlocation\%%~ni" (dir "%%i" | find "0 File(s)" > NUL & if errorlevel 1 xcopy /y "%%i\*.*" "d:\newlocation\%%~ni") else (xcopy /y "%%i" "d:\newlocation")
xcopy /y c:\*.* d:\newlocation\
```

But it said something about bad parameter...

http://prntscr.com/6fvl4t
Edit2: I am using a batch file.

Comment: From a cmd prompt, `xcopy /?`.  [Examples here](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html).

Comment: Which one have you tried and what happened?

Comment: Anyone? I need this today.